# How to hide media stream url

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

I have a link like this: http://example.com/temp/test/index.php?v=**de72800bf2682d7d1b808e48cf351543db88c7a0**
I have a datatable row like this:
ID=1, Title="short movie", direct_url="http://example.com/temp/test/Ideas(short_film).webm", "indirect_url = "**de72800bf2682d7d1b808e48cf351543db88c7a0**"
I wanna do so: If I go to the link that I mentioned above, in that page will be video tag:

```
<video src="**http://example.com/temp/test/index.php?v=de72800bf2682d7d1b808e48cf351543db88c7a0**"></video>
```

And it starts to play video from direct url http://example.com/temp/test/Ideas(short_film).webm, but it will not appear in the page, so nobody can use the direct link. By which way I can do this? Maybe Javascript, maybe php can help me, but I don't know. Help me, please.

Comment: Maybe by pulling the server of the internet? Maybe by pressing the power off button?

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to prevent capturing or saving the video? **Impossible**

Do you want to hide the URL? **Impossible**

That's impossible because the browser needs to access it. And that information is saved at some place (e.g. in the network traffic list).

Even if you would find other ways of streaming/sending the video information, it won't go directly to the browser. The information is passed through many stations and one of it could copy the data.

Comment: But, how youtube do this? For exp: http://youtube.com/watch?v=eH21F83F and I cannot find any direct url in youtube.

Comment: Youtube uses a flash player but that does not change the fact that the data has to be transmitted to the client. AFAIK, YT has also some direct links for `*.flv`. If you try the experimental HTML 5 interface in YT, YT will even embed a `<video>` tag which will include a *src* attribute pointing to the video itself. Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/33WXn/2. **Edit:** Note that you can't insert the *src* URL into VLC and play back. I think YT is making some redirections here but you can find out the definitive URL via Chrome's developer tools which will show you the actual stream URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. If my browser can request the URL, I can see the URL. You'll have to look into other ways of protecting your content.

Answer (score -1):

You can certainly do this with php.

If a user opens a page which contains 
`<video src="**http://example.com/temp/test/index.php?v=de72800bf2682d7d1b808e48cf351543db88c7a0**"></video>`

Your index.php should perform the lookup to determine the video file's path *which should not be web accessible*, open that file and then stream it to the browser.